# ionic 3 image picker & preview like instagram

Tags: image, cordova, ionic-framework, photo

I'm developing an ionic 3 application like instagram, to let users pick photos from their phone album, while they can preview the photo on the same page.

I've tried cordova-plugin-photo-library [here](https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library), but there's no limit function so I have to get all photos from user album, which could be very large volume. Users have to wait until all photos are loaded before they can click and select one picture. This is really bad user experience.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks.

Comment: have you found solution to this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use base64 image

```
 # view 
 <img *ngFor='let image of images' [src]="DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/jpeg;base64,'+image)" style="width: 100px;height:100px;" [hidden]="lastImage === null">

 # choice select method
 public presentActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: 'choice select method',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'gallery',
          handler: () => {
            this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'take image',
          handler: () => {
            this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'cancel',
          role: 'cancel'
        }
      ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }



  public takePicture(sourceType) {
  // Create options for the Camera Dialog
  var options = {
    quality: 100,
    sourceType: sourceType,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    allowEdit: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    targetWidth: 600,
    targetHeight: 600,
    correctOrientation: true,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
  };

  // Get the data of an image
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
    // Special handling for Android library
    if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM) {
this.images.push(imagePath);



    } else {
      this.images.push(imagePath);


    }
  }, (err) => {
    this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
  });

}
```

Comment: His question was asking about restricting the number of photos to pull in. Like query selectors: top & skip.

Comment: Thanks mohammad mahmoodi but this solution won't allow me to change the UI by adding a real time preview box when user is selecting the pictures (just like Instagram). Or do you have any idea how can achieve that?

Comment: @pezetter Exactly. Any ideas? Thanks.